# Как проверить есть ли на устройстве доступ к интернету?

Tags: java, android

Как можно проверить есть ли на устройстве доступ к интернету?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Функция

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

И в манифест:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts)

Comment: если вернется true значит есть соединение с инетом?

Comment: да, смотрите название функции - `isOnline`

Comment: спасибо помогли

Answer (score 10):

Хотелось бы кое что добавить.

Если Вам требуется проверить наличие какого либо соединения, то [метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506368/176223) предложенный **Андрей**'ем безусловно подойдет.

Однако, если необходимо проверить наличие именно **интернета** на устройстве, то метод может работать не так, как мы ожидаем. В качестве примера приведу такую ситуацию:

Имеется `WLAN` без доступа к интернет, и устройство, которое к этой сети подключено. Как думаете, что вернет метод `isOnline()`?- ответ true.

Если же такая ситуация неприемлема, то приведу код для проверки реального интернет соединения, честно позаимствованный [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27312494/4728929).

```
public boolean isReallyOnline() {

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {

        Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int     exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
        return (exitValue == 0);

    } catch (IOException e)          { e.printStackTrace(); } 
      catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: понял, спасибо)))

Comment: @ermak0ff Если касается мобильного устройства на android, что писать в `runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");`?

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов да собственно говоря это и есть код для мобильного устройства на android...прям так и должно работать