# SplashActivity.java как проверить интернет соединение?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть SplashActivity.java, которая включается при запуске приложения. Помогите мне вставить в него код проверки интернет-соединения, если нет интернета, перенаправить на другой вид деятельности, а не на мой вид деятельности, где я бы показал, что нет подключения к Интернету.

SplashActivity.java

```
package com.com.apps.apps.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.com.apps.apps.R;
import com.com.apps.apps.activities.MainActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "SplashActivity";
    private final static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;

    ImageView splashLogo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Inside of Splash activity onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        splashLogo = findViewById(R.id.splash_logo);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506366/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%83

Comment: Это не самое лучшее решение. Предположим, вы определите, что интернета нет и направите на экран. А интернет уже появился. Или наоборот. Вы определите, что он есть, направите на другой экран и интернет пропадёт в процессе перехода. По идее, вам надо не эту задачу решать, а задачу обработки неуспешных сетевых соединений.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вы правы, ведь узнав, что его нет, его скорее всего включат, но можно сделать кнопку что-то вроде (переподключится) и проверять наличие интернета с помощью функции, что выше и если оно есть перенаправлять. Так же делать проверку при открытии самой SplashActivity

Comment: SplashActivity проверить если нет интернета отобразить что либо чтобы включили интернет и перезапустили приложение, потом включают переходят в активность и в активности тоже чекается интернет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте broadcastreceiver который будет ловить эти события:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    int status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
    Log.e("Sulod sa network reciever", "Sulod sa network reciever");
    if ("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        if (status == NetworkUtil.NETWORK_STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            //.....
        } else {
            //.....
        }
   }
}
}
```

Дополнительный класс:

```
public class NetworkUtil {
public static final int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
public static final int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
public static final int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;
public static final int NETWORK_STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;
public static final int NETWORK_STATUS_WIFI = 1;
public static final int NETWORK_STATUS_MOBILE = 2;

public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return TYPE_WIFI;

        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            return TYPE_MOBILE;
    } 
    return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
}
```

И объявите broadcastreceiver в манифесте

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <receiver
    android:name="NetworkChangeReceiver"
    android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```